# Can not download an image created with gd library if it is within a session

Tags: php, session, gd

i have a code like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['log']) || $_SESSION['log'] != $_POST['accesso']){
  exit(":)");
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$image_width = 200;
$image_height = 40;
$image = imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);
imagejpeg($image);

?>
```

If I try to save the image or with the right mouse button or with the command ctrl+s, nothing happens. If I remove the session `session_start();` everything works again.

Solutions?

Comment: please post output of `var_dump($_SESSION, $_POST);` and write more about desired behaviour.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7u4B7ZCF

I just need to save the image to the user if he wants to do it.

Comment: So you have `$_SESSION['log']` set AND it's value is the same as `$_POST['accesso']`, so the first condition is met and everything should work just fine. But the main thing is: you do not put anything in the image (there's nothing there). Follow the example of creating images: http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php#example-3303

Comment: I try this code http://pl1.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php#example-3303
but nothing changes.
Return to normal if comment session_start();

Comment: Please update your question and make it as precise as you can (what you want to achieve and how this should work).

Comment: Hello, the problem is the same as I wrote before. The image is not saved if the session exists.
"If I try to save the image or with the right mouse button or with the command ctrl+s, nothing happens. If I remove the session session_start(); everything works again."

Answer (score 0):

OK, after "discussing" it in the comments and with you refusing to provide more info, the best I could do is guess what's the problem. So:

1. Without the `session_start()` there is no $_SESSION global. Server does not start or persist session at all, so you should not be able to download the image at all (as `!isset($_SESSION['log'])` should always return TRUE in that case. If it does not, I assume you have `session.auto_start` set to 1 in your php.ini file (which tells the server to start session on every request. I'd set it to 0 and see if that changes anything).
2. Remember that with session active (`session_start()` called) anything you store in your $_SESSION variable will be there until either the session times out, you change your session cookie ("forget" your session id), or explicitly remove said value from `$_SESSION` (like this: `unset($_SESSION['log']);`). Try unsetting $_SESSION['log'] or changing it somehow and see what happens.
3. In your place I'd add a directive like below at the very beginning of your script, to help me debug:

`error_reporting(E_ALL); /* report all errors no matter what type */
ini_set('display_errors', 1); /* display errors to output */`

Also, if really the `session_start()` is your problem, you really should read about how sessions work in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php.

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL); ->no error
ini_set('display_errors', 1); -> no output error

I tried 
     session_unset (); 
     session_destroy (); 

but nothing has changed.

I can't change my php.ini. I need contact my provider.